# How to redirect all extensions after .php to the file with .php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

According to Google Webmaster Tools, I have many crawl errors related to weird URL extensions added to my existing pages.

For example, this page is displayed normally:
http://www.normalbreathing.com/causes/cold-feet-hands-causes.php

However, somehow, there are these weird URLs somehow generated from the previous URL:
http://www.normalbreathing.com/causes/cold-feet-hands-causes.php/CO2.php
and similar others.

These weird URLs are displayed in major browsers, but with many mistakes (no images and all links wrong). As a result, these weird pages generate numerous crawl errors for bots.

How can I redirect all extensions after ".php" (note that these weird extensions often have extra ".php" or something like "/%20" etc.) to the correct files with only one ".php" using .htaccess?

I found a similar query:
[.htaccess redirect all extension to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158940/htaccess-redirect-all-extension-to-php/15160043#15160043)

but it is not exactly the same because it says "To use it, be sure that you don't have URL with a dot and an alphanumeric string at the end." I do have those dots and sometimes strings with numbers after ".php".

Answer (score 0):

Google is referring to the `.php/.php` on your URL. a site that I have found useful is:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

There are really major problems with your website.

Just point all your css, js, images to absolute paths like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.normalbreathing.com/text2.css" type="text/css" />
```

Whenever you have a `/` it figures that it's a directory. So going `../` will not point to the proper place.

Same story with hrefs. not one link from here http://www.normalbreathing.com/d/cold-feet.php/CO2.php works. Because it starts with `../`

I strongly recommend fixing HTML before going into `.htaccess`